# References to arbitrary (generic) Objects

Tags: java

I've been trying to emulate Python lists in Java; i.e., maintaining a dynamic array, which can store different types of objects simultaneously. Is there any way in Java to have a generic object reference, i.e., an object reference that can point to any type of object, user defined or built-in?

Comment: `Object` is the way as it is the parent class of all reference types in Java.

Comment: Why do you need to "emulate" anything? What's wrong with `List<Object>`?

Comment: Everything in Java extends `Object`, so you can always do `List<Object>` to store any type of `Object`.  That said, the whole reason for Java generics is because storing different types of `Object` in the same `Array` or `List` or whatever (with rare exceptions) is really bad programming practice as it tends to obfuscate meaning
.

Comment: Think of it as an academic exercise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding lists in Python. While they *can* hold objects of different types, they are not designed to: Python lists were designed to be *homogenous* data structures. By contrast, tuples were meant to be heterogeneous (and those have are immutable).

You can mimic tuples in Java by doing something like:

```
class Tuple1<A> { 
    private final A a; 
    public Tuple1(A a) { 
        this.a = a; 
    } 
}

class Tuple2<A, B> { 
    private final A a; 
    private final B b; 
    public Tuple2(A a, B b) { 
        this.a = a; 
        this.b = b; 
    } 
}

class Tuple3<A, B, C> { 
    private final A a; 
    private final B b; 
    private final C c;
    public Tuple3(A a, B b, C c) { 
        this.a = a; 
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c; 
    } 
}

...
```

You could consider having a `Tuple` base class or interface with an `index()` method and an overloaded static factory method.

It would be possible to use variables of type `Object` to store any and all instances. However, very rarely is this what you want to do. You should narrow this down to exactly what you're trying to store and work with that as opposed to `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

Everything in Java extends `Object`, so you can always do `List<Object>` to store any type of `Object`.

That said, the whole reason for Java generics is because storing different types of `Object` in the same `Array` or `List` or whatever (with rare exceptions) is *really* bad programming practice as it tends to obfuscate *meaning* and make things harder to *maintain*.